# How to check if background script has stopped with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, background-process, ubuntu-10.04

I have a script which keeps running on a **screen** as **background job** continuously on my Ubuntu server. But sometimes if some error occurs it can stop. Is there any way by which I can **monitor** it and get some alert when it stops instead of manually logging and checking that the script is running or not ??

I am running my server on Linode and Ubuntu is 10.04 server edition.